# How can select id and other attributes with group - using pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose model name is Modal

`results = Modal.select('number, min(price) as min_price').group('number')`

Loop over results in view

```
  <%= results.each do |result| %>
    <%= result.number %>
    <%= result.min_price %>
  <%= end %>
```

I want

```
<%= result.number %>
<%= result.price %>
<%= result.id %>
<%= result.somethingelse %>
```

how is it possible.`Modal.select('number, min(price) as min_price').group('number')` in this query

Comment: Sazzad, try my answer. It will solve your problem. If it does so, consider accepting the answer. To see how accepting answer works, please see this post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this in your view:

```
<%= result.number %>
<%= result.price %>
<%= result.id %>
<%= result.somethingelse %>
```

Then, you have to select all those columns in your query like this:

```
results = Modal.select('number, min(price) as min_price, price, id, somethingelse').group('number')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to console your code and see that your query creates a brand new object that has limited columns. Only the one you specified in select(). In this case, you should try to use * or specify the columns that you needs